# Simplification of Maxwell equations assuming that the induced fields are much weaker than the applied fields

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction, magnetohydrodynamics

In cases where induced fields are much smaller than the applied fields, are there any terms in the Maxwell equations that can be neglected? I tried to do a simple scaling analysis to come up with a solution, but did not succeed. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "induced fields" and "applied fields"?  By "induced fields", do you mean, e.g., the E field induced by a changing H field?  If so, then all you need to do is make all quantities in the equations non time-dependent.

Comment: Yes, I meant the fields induced by the change in the other field.
Can you provide a scaling argument in support of your answer?

Comment: Are you looking for an argument along the lines of proving that as the partial derivative with respect to time approaches zero, the induced field approaches zero?

Comment: Yes, something like a dimensional analysis

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the answer is really very simple. These are Maxwell's equations:

$∇^2E=k∂^2E/∂t^2$,

$∇^2B=k∂^2B/∂t^2$,

$∇⋅E=4πρ$, and

$∇⋅B=0$.

If you set the right-hand sides of the top two equations to zero, the only solutions will have no time dependence and therefore no induced field.  You *could* make it a bit more complicated: start with the full set of equations, set $E = E_o(x) + w F(t)$, and find the limit as $w ->0$, but you would end up with essentially the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The general representation of [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) in vacuum is given by:
$$
\begin{align}
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} & = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_{o}} \tag{0} \\
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} & = 0 \tag{1} \\
  \nabla \times \mathbf{E} & = - \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{ \partial t } \tag{2} \\
  \nabla \times \mathbf{B} & = \mu_{o} \ \mathbf{j} + \frac{1}{c^{2}} \ \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{ \partial t } \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
where $c^{-2} = \mu_{o} \ \varepsilon_{o}$ is the speed of light defined by the product of the permitivity and permeability of free space.  We can take the curl of Equations 2 and 3 to find:
$$
\begin{align}
  \nabla^{2} \mathbf{E} - \frac{1}{c^{2}} \ \frac{\partial^{2} \mathbf{E}}{ \partial t^{2} } & = \frac{1}{\varepsilon_{o}} \left( \nabla \rho + \frac{1}{c^{2}} \ \frac{\partial \mathbf{j}}{ \partial t } \right) \tag{4} \\
  \nabla^{2} \mathbf{B} - \frac{1}{c^{2}} \ \frac{\partial^{2} \mathbf{B}}{ \partial t^{2} } & = - \mu_{o} \ \nabla \times \mathbf{j} \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
where these are referred to as the [wave equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) for $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.

> In cases where induced fields are much smaller than the applied fields, are there any terms in the Maxwell equations that can be neglected?

By "induced fields" I am assuming you are referring to [electromagnetic induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction), correct?  If so, then you can take the terms $\frac{\partial}{ \partial t } \rightarrow 0$, which will reduce the problem to an [electrostatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatics) or [magnetostatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostatics) one.

Note that you can still induce electrical charges under the electrostatic approximation, i.e., called [electrostatic induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_induction).  It's really just a redistribution of charges.  If you neglect this effect as well, then let $\rho \rightarrow 0$.